# Clarification on the rules of Top Trumps when two or more cards win

Tags: top-trumps

The [rules](http://www.toptrumps.com/how-to-play-top-trumps/) state:

> If two or more cards share the top value or data is not available for that particular subject then all the cards are placed in the middle and the same player chooses again from the next card. The winner of the hand takes the cards in the middle as well.

However, what they don't make clear is:

1. Does every player continue to play in this case?  (If two players have the same top value and a third player does not, does the third player continue to play – and possibly even win the hand?)
2. What happens if this situation occurs on a player's last card?  They cannot carry on but have not yet lost the hand!

Is there some *de facto* rule that's used in each of these circumstances?  Or is there an official rule that is just hard to find?

Answer (score 2):

As it's written, drawing a hand confers no advantage to the people who played the top cards. It's not that the same hand continues, it's just that there's now a bonus stack of cards available for the winner of the next hand.

In this way, if your last card was put into the middle like this then you're simply out of the game. You didn't win the hand, and you have no way to win the next hand to claim the bonus.

Now for the extra bit that the rules don't cover: if you were the player choosing the category and this happened, I'd have the next player either become someone else at random, someone who's obviously doing the worst, or just have you pick the category but not play a card.